# I'm trying to create a quiz with a picture for each question. Im using switch statement. Is a way to simplify the code as I have 20 questions?

Tags: javascript, arrays, switch-statement

```
const assignPictures = (value, questionID) => {
  const addPicture = document.createElement("div");
  addPicture.setAttribute("class","imagesInQuestion")

  switch(true){
    case value === secondArray[0]:
      addPicture.innerHTML = `<img class="inlineImages" src ="/Images/Block1.png">`
      break;

    case value === secondArray[1]:
      addPicture.innerHTML = `<img class="inlineImages" src ="/Images/Block2.png">`
      break;
   }
   return document.querySelector(questionID).append(addPicture);
}
```

Comment: Once you indetify *which* `secondArray` element matches, you can use the index to compute the `src` path.

Comment: I just updated my answer, does it fits your need better?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Based on OP's comment, you could use an array to associate each question with a path to a file. Then, you would use this array to display the good image based on the current question index:

```js
const assignPictures = (value, questionID) => {
    // each item is the path to the relevant image
    const images = [
        '/Images/Block1.png',
        '/another_path.jpg',
        'https://external.image.jpg',
    ];

    // if `questionID` is not a numerical index, adjust `images` accordingly:
    // const images = {
    //     firstQuestion: '/Images/Block1.png',
    //     anotherID: '/another_path.jpg',
    //     whyNot: 'https://external.image.jpg',
    // }

    const addPicture = document.createElement("div");
    addPicture.setAttribute("class", "imagesInQuestion")
    // assuming `questionID` is the current question number
    addPicture.innerHTML = `<img class="inlineImages" src ="${images[questionID]}">`
    document.querySelector(questionID).append(addPicture);
}
```

---

Please, note that we are using backticks to create a template literal:

```js
// This allows us to use this syntax:
`<img class="inlineImages" src ="${images[questionID]}">`

// rather than this one:
'<img class="inlineImages" src ="' + images[questionID] + '">';
```

Comment: Good answer, but maybe you should emphasize that you didn't just use single quotes but backticks in order to make a placeholder string as they look very similar

Comment: The author used backticks as well but I'll add a comment to emphasize this, you are right @natre214

Comment: Oops, you're right, I didn't see that the OP used it too :)

Comment: As you said, they are quite similar @natre214 ^^

Comment: Won't this append 20 img's to the same dom element?  I don't see the point of a loop here.  Isn't the right approach to associate the img urls with the different questionId's, then do just a lookup here?

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion, I'm trying to add a specific picture for a specific question. Therefore I have 20 pictures for 20 questions, however, only 5 (random) will appear on the screen. This is why I tried using switch statement.

Comment: Ow, it seems I misunderstood the question indeed @danh.